# How to install LAMP server or any suitable control panel in Tomcat enabled Amazon Linux?

Tags: tomcat, phpmyadmin, lamp

How to install LAMP server or any suitable control panel in Tomcat enabled Amazon Linux? I have installed Tomcat 8, MySQL 5.5, PHP 5.6. I found that phpMyAdmin could not be configured in Tomcat as this is written in PHP and Tomcat is Java based, so which LAMP server or replacement of phpMyAdmin can I use in my Amazon Linux ec2 server?

Comment: You can run the LAMP stack and Tomcat at the same time. If you have set up Tomcat to run, say, on port `8080`, then bring Apache up on port `8081`, and run phpMyAdmin from there.

Comment: Also, please read [this community discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495) about urgent begging, thanks.